# Windows Taskbar show titles option not showing up

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar

[image: link to the image of the problem]

my taskbar is not locked and I still cant see the show titles option. the reason I want it so that I can centre all my icons and do that I need the links option, but if there is another way to centre all my icons let me know!

Answer (score 0):

The "Show titles" option is not there any longer.

To find it, select "Taskbar settings" from the context menu,
which will get you to
*Settings > Personalisation > Taskbar*.

Then under "Combine taskbar buttons", select any option which is *not*
"Always hide labels".
In your case, where there are a lot of icons, choose "Never".
You might also need to enlarge the height of the taskbar to
more than one line.

Comment: Well, this worked but I am so sorry if I was not clear with my question. I actually wanted that so that I could use the links " || " to centre my icons, is there any other way to centre my icons??

Comment: What do you mean by "centering icons"?